# Cleanest way to get value from secondary form

Tags: c#

I've written a simple program that reads barcodes from a page and will ask the user to select one to use. I have a few methods that use the results of that form and I was wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to execute the following code:

```
string barcode = "";    

if (barcodes.Count > 1)
{
    using (var form = new frmSelectBarcode(barcodes))
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            barcode = form.getSelection();
        }
    }
}

//Do other things
```

I feel like it's fairly clean, but I don't like that there's 3 levels of indentation and I'm not sure if that should be necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. The best would be to post at least two complete methods where you use the results.

Comment: Unfortunately this is actually all the relevant code. The results are only used here to assign barcode once. It is never used again. It would be safe to assume form.getselection() just returns the string "TEST123" every time. It is a near single line of code form. @Heslacher

Comment: What technology is this? Please use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us going through your code

- better assign String.Empty than "" to a variable your aging eyes will thank you in a few years.
- objects should be named  using `PascalCase` casing
- public methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing as well

I would add a `Public static string GetBarcode(List<Barcode> barcodes)` method to your `frmSelectBarcode` class like so.

```
Public static string GetBarcode(List<Barcode> barcodes)
{
    if (barcodes.Count <= 1)
    {
        return string. Empty;
    } 
    using (var form = new frmSelectBarcode(barcodes)) 
    { 
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
        { 
            return form.getSelection(); 
        } 
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

In this way you have only one place where you need to maintain the code and it's quite easy to call where ever you need the result like so

```
string barcode = frmSelectBarcode.GetBarcode(barcodes) ;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I thought of. The code snippet from OP has the responsibility of determining whether or not the user needs to be prompted to choose a barcode. That will fit right in with the actual Form responsible for gathering this feedback. The main change I'd suggest to this version is to `throw` when `barcodes` is empty (you're going to have to check for empty string anyway, might as well check for an exception instead). Also, this function could have logic to `return barcodes[0]` if there is only one element.

Comment: The logic is different from the OP. The first line should be `if (barcodes.Count <= 1)`

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer good catch. Answering from mobile isn't that good. Fixed.